# 100 user cap for OAuth to Google API for unverified app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

Our Google app uses a scope that's subject to Google's verification process outlined here: [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).

We use two Google oauth apps: production and staging. Our production environment has been verified (after an extensive security review). Our staging environment has not been verified, and so we're subject to the 100-user cap outlined in "Exceptions to verification requirements" in [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914).

However, we need to be able create more than 100 accounts to test our "new user sign up" flow. After we use these test accounts, we no longer need them to have access. Currently, new accounts are seeing "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app".

Is there a workaround for the 100 user cap in which we can remove access to test accounts that we're no longer using?

Comment: Does using google groups works?

Comment: nope - these need be individual google accounts for oauth to work

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add more then 100 test users while your project is still in the testing phase.  It is also not possible to remove a user once they have been added as a test user.

> While publishing status is set to "Testing", only test users are able to access the app. Allowed user cap prior to app verification is 100, and is counted over the entire lifetime of the app.

This does not change even if your app is part of the  [Exceptions to verification requirements](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Cexceptions-to-verification-requirements) section you are still limited to 100 usrs

> Note that your app will be subject to the unverified app screen and the 100-user cap will be in effect.

[Unverified apps](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)

Answer (score -1):

As per this support [doc](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764) you can try to request a quota increase with the following [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_quota_increase).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that's only to request "tokens per day". The limit of 100 users is a hard cap.