# Google apps script This app is blocked error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, oauth

I have a group of 100 people helping me test a currently unverified google sheet that contains app script and just got an error that popped up for one user that says:

This app is blocked
This app tried to access sensitive info in your Google Account. To keep your account safe, Google blocked this access.

Im not certain yet if it has anything to do with the app itself. I have tried removing the security settings for unverified apps but no luck. I came across this post related to a 100 user cap quota for unverified apps:
[100 user cap for OAuth to Google API for unverified app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662162/100-user-cap-for-oauth-to-google-api-for-unverified-app)

However, im not sure this would apply for me... hoping someone could shed some like how this works for my situation, where each user makes a copy of the main sheet that contains the code and then saves the sheet in their own google account (the sheet uses their google drive account as well to save files to once done using the script in their file). Im trying to figure out if this 100 user cap quota will apply or if since they are making a copy of the sheet and essentially taking ownership of it by making a copy, wouldn't it just be theirs unverified app at that point and no longer tied to the original? Or does google somehow still link them and imposed auth limits?

Not looking for a solution to the error but more clarity around how my situation I described applies to potential quota limits or other potential related errors I may encounter trying to test the tool in this manner. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your users make a copy of your spreadsheet and then run the script, they will see a popup like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2rTX.jpg).
In this popup, they should see their own Gmail address as the developer's account.
Since the quota is linked to the developer account, your users will have their own quotas.

Comment: Pode ter ocorrido de este usuário não ter aceito a execução do script!